# Осуществить поиск объекта со Spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring

Есть такой объект

```
public class DepositMatrix implements Serializable, Cloneable {
public static final String PRODUCT_LOOKUP_MAIN = "Product.LookupMain";
public static final String PRODUCT_LOOKUP = "Product.Lookup";
public static final String PRODUCT_LOOKUP2 = "Product.Lookup2";
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "DEPOSIT_MATRIX_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "DEPOSIT_MATRIX_SEQ", sequenceName = "DEPOSIT_MATRIX_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
private String deposit_name;
@Column(name = "service_package")
private String servicePackage;
private String deposit_chanel;
private String risk_style;
private String currency;
@Column(name = "range_from", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal range_from;
@Column(name = "range_to", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal range_to;
@Column(name = "period_from", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer periodFrom;
@Column(name = "period_to", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer periodTo;
@Column(name = "deposit_nr", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal deposit_nr;
@Column(name = "deposit_er", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal deposit_er;
private String refilable;
private String withdraw;
@Column(name = "add_payment_min", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal add_payment_min;
@Column(name = "balance_min", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal balance_min;
@Column(name = "withdraw_min", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal withdraw_min;
@Column(name = "prod_type")
private String prodType;
private String description;
@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR")
private String cap;
@Column(name = "limit_prol", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer limit_prol;
@Column(name = "addpayment_c_day_end", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer addpayment_c_day_end;
@Column(name = "withdraw_c_day_start", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer withdraw_c_day_start;
@Column(name = "withdraw_c_day_end", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer withdraw_c_day_end;
private String comm_code;
private String segment_list;
@Column(name = "pens_flg")
private String pensFlg;
@Column(name = "voen_pens_flg")
private String voenPensFlg;
@Column(name = "vip")
private String vip;
@Column(name = "job_flg")
private String jobFlg;
@Column(name = "uik_client")
private String uikClient;
@Column(name = "amount", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal amount;
@Column(name = "pay_type", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private BigDecimal payType;
@Column(name = "cap_period", columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
private Integer cap_period;
private String prod_code;
```

Был создан его экземпляр, и засечены значения

```
DepositMatrix depositMatrix1 = new DepositMatrix();
    depositMatrix1.setCurrency(request.getCurrency());
```

Возможно ли вернуть список строк из БД, набор значения полей, которых соответствует значениям в моем объекте

Когда так пытаюсь найти эти объекты выдает ошибку:

```
List<DepositMatrix> findDepositMatrix(DepositMatrix depositMatrix);
```

Как правильно сформировать сигнатуру в интерфейсе, чтобы осуществить поиск объекта?

Comment: Не лучший вариант. По факту вы должны сравнить все поля со всеми. Я бы на вашем месте попробовал подойти к проблеме с другой стороны. Например, расчитать хеш-код для нужных полей и при записи сохранять его в специальную переменную, а потом производить поиск по этому значению. Если этот поиск основной, то возможно есть смысл сделать таблицу один ко многим во избежание коллизий, а хеш сделать айдишником

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть класс `Example`

```
DepositMatrix depositMatrix1 = new DepositMatrix();
depositMatrix1.setCurrency(request.getCurrency());
Example<DepositMatrix> depositMatrixExample = Example.of(depositMatrix1);

List<DepositMatrix> list = depositMatrixRepository.findAll(depositMatrixExample);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое